# Run Sass in .bat file

Tags: ruby, batch-file, sass, command-prompt

For some reason I am having trouble running Sass in a .bat file. I can copy and paste a list of commands into a command prompt and they run fine. However, when I put the sass command into a .bat file file will stop executing after it runs sass. In the below example csstidy is never run. Does the ruby engine not return like my commands? Any ideas?

Example.bat

```
...(list of commands that run fine)
sass eng.scss eng-sass.css
csstidy eng-less.css eng-sass.tidy.css
```

I'm running Win7x64

Comment: After spending some more time on it I was able to fix it by putting "call" in front of the sass command.

    ...(list of commands that run fine)
    call eng.scss eng-sass.css
    csstidy eng-less.css eng-sass.tidy.css