# How to keep cmd window open after executing sass compiler batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sass, windows-10

I am having trouble getting this to work:

I created a batch file with following code to perform sass compilation:

```
@echo Sass Compiler
pause
d:
cd D:\Users\xyz\custom-bootstrap
sass --update --no-cache --sourcemap=none myBootstrapFile.scss
@pause
```

The thing is, the cmd window always closes after sass is done (sass performes what its supposed to do), even though I tried `pause` and `cmd /k` at the last line. I execute the file by doubleclicking it in the explorer on windows 10.

How can I keep the cmd window open? All the other answers I saw for this problem didnt work.

Comment: Try: `CALL sass --update --no-cache --sourcemap=none myBootstrapFile.scss`

Comment: @Squashman Thanks that did it! Can you explain why I need to use it though?

Comment: If `sass` is actually "sass.bat" or "sass.cmd", then `call` is required to force CMD to resume the current batch script after it's finished executing `sass`.

Comment: @voiDnyx, I have not used SASS but the description of your problem tells me that `SASS` is a batch file.  When you execute a batch file from another batch file, process control is transferred to the other batch file and does not return to the original batch file unless you use the `CALL` command.

Comment: A quick search for batch-file sass on Stackoverflow would have found you this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237213/run-sass-in-bat-file